# Black screen after login Kubuntu 16.04 on QHD monitor

Tags: kubuntu, display, display-resolution

I have a new PC with ASRock N3150DC-ITX mobo and a HiRes AOC Q2577PMQ QHD monitor. The monitor is connected via DisplayPort. I have installed Kubuntu 16.04 LTS from scratch, but I get a black screen right after logging in. Switching to TTY also shows just a black screen, but the system seems to be running, as I can blindly type 'shutdown' and the system goes off. I can see the console when I switch to TTY before login. I borrowed an FHD monitor from my daughter and connected it via DVI, and could see the desktop after login, but I want to use mine one. It looks like the system does not recognize the monitor or its resolution.
How can I solve this problem? Can I temporarily force the system to run in FHD resolution? I've tried using 'sudo xrandr -d :0' from TTY before login, but with no success (Can't Open Display error, maybe because the desktop is not running).
I will try to use HDMI cable tonight, but I'm not sure this will help. Unfortunately, the monitor came with a useless DVI-D Single Link cable, so I have to buy a Dual Link one to give it a try (in this case only 1920x1200 @ 60Hz is supported), but I still want a QHD to be supported.
This is my first Linux experience, so I'm a little disappointed. Don't make me turn to Windows, please :) Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: And your GPU model?

Comment: Intel Celeron N3150 built-in Intel® HD Graphics.

Comment: I have connected the monitor via HDMI, and it shows me the desktop now! The resolution is QHD, 2560*1440 60Hz. Nevertheless, I'll continue struggling to make it running via DisplayPort.